# ASP.NET Core - Using Partial Views inside a Modal window for my Add/Edit/View Details screens?

Tags: design, design-patterns, .net, ajax, asp.net-core

I've been developing .NET projects for the past 3 years, and on my recent web .NET projects, I've been using Partial Views for all the screens that contain Forms for Add/Update/Delete or other information (e.g. User Info).

Here's a sample (not the exact code) of how I designed it.

For example on editing a user:

```
HTML - (A table that contains information about users)

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Edit</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>94</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="LoadHtmlContent('94')"> Edit </button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

Javascript (Function that is executed when the user clicks the Edit button on the table)

function LoadHtmlContent(id)
{
   var id = id; // Get the id from a table row 
   var url = $("#EditUrl").val(); //Get the URL from a hidden input
   $.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: "GET"
   data: data, //optional
   success: function(response){
     if(response.success=true){
       $("#modal").html(response.content);
       $("#modal").show();
    }
     else{
       alert(response.message)
    }
   }
  )};
}

Controller:

public ActionResult LoadEditableScreen(int id)
{
   //Perform Security/Authorization checks here
  if(!Authorized)
  {
      return Json(new {success=false, message="Access Denied"});
  }
   var model = new ViewModel();
   //Load data from database layer here
   var partialView = CreatePartialView("_editScreen", model) //helper function 
   return Json(new {success=true, content = partialView });
   
}
```

Is this a good practice to use in my future projects as well? I'm seeing this not only from my perspective as developer, but from the user's as well. Because as a user its much easier for me to have everything I need on a single page without having to navigate through many pages. I've created this in a way that is dynamic and it can fit into all my pages and any type of data.

Thank you :)

Comment: I use a similar technique in a single-page application.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a precursor variant to the single page application. There's nothing wrong with that. This style of development is precisely why MVC is able to return partial views as a response.

If you like this style of development, look into single page application (SPA) development. While this shifts the development from MVC/Razor to pure frontend (JS/TS), it further enhances the user experience that you get from this kind of design.